# I Need to Collect the Product Randomly, with store id

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-collection

I want to show the Product with randomly on particular site from Multistore and **Status** is **enabled**, **Stock** is **Instock** and Select the All attributes from these collection of Product In Magento **Home Page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:- Make a phtml file

```
<?php   
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$bestseller_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$bestseller_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$bestseller_collection->setStoreId($storeId);
$bestseller_collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
$bestseller_collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($bestseller_collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($bestseller_collection); 
$bestseller_collection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$bestseller_collection->getSelect()->limit(10);

    foreach ($bestseller_collection as $_product)
    {
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().$_product['url_path']; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">// product name
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(270,270); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product['name']) ?>"/> // product image
    }
?>
```

Step2:- Include this phtml to cms Home page layout xml

Step3:- Clear the cache.